# How to get the shortName from an FQDN

Tags: java, scala, fqdn

I'm struggling with getting the `shortName` from an `FQDN`. The main problem with the FQDN is that it can come in various forms, such as:

```
FQDN => ShortName 
node.a.domain.net => node.a
node.a.dev.domain.net => node.a.dev
node.a.sbx.domain.net => node.a.sbx
node.a.b.domain.net => node.a.b
node.a.dev.dom-as-me.domain.net => node.a.dev
node.a.dom-as-me.domain.net => node.a
```

I'm using `Java` or `Scala` to accomplish this, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As Ralf says below, you do not have enough information to distinguish without som kind of list, but it might be easier to make a list of shortnames or last part of shortnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic way to do that.

You want to split the FQDN at some dot position into the "short name" and the "domain". From just looking at the string, there's no way, it needs additional knowledge.

```
FQDN => ShortName 
node.a.domain.net => node.a
node.a.dev.domain.net => node.a.dev (Why not node.a in dev.domain.net?)
node.a.sbx.domain.net => node.a.sbx
node.a.b.domain.net => node.a.b
node.a.dev.dom-as-me.domain.net => node.a.dev (Why not node.a.dev.dom-as-me in domain.net?)
node.a.dom-as-me.domain.net => node.a
```

You need a dictionary of domains, then you can identify string tails that are listed in the dictionary and

- use the tail as the domain
- and the head as the short name.

Answer (score 0):

Found that InetAddress do the work:

```
InetAddress.getByName(host).getCanonicalHostName == host
```